# loading any web site to an electron desktop app and manipulate it

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have to build a multiplataform desktop app that loads any website that I want inside the desktop app, I dont want to open my google chrome or firefox.
Researching I came across Electron. It is possible to this in electron?

If it is possible, do I have any control over the web site, for example, can I spot all the forms and complete them with dummy data?

Comment: Yes, i think that is somehow possible.

Comment: Electron is a "browser", just without the (default) address bar and buttons, but some security aspects (https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security)! So you have control over all the HTML/forms as well, like you do inside browser development tools